How can a script know the directory it resides in?
I work on a Solaris 8 machine and have a script which is being sourced. The script wants to know in which path itself is located. I tried multiple solutions from e.g. Unix shell script find out which directory the script file resides? , but all of them are based on $0 or pwd. I tried this so far:
$ echo $OS
SunOS
$ echo $OSTYPE
solaris
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 2.02.1(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.5.1)
Copyright 1998 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ pwd
/home/username
$ cat source-me/source-me 
pwd
echo $PWD
echo $0
echo ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
$ . source-me/source-me 
/home/username
/home/username
-bash

$

Is the task solveable at all?

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028 Have you read that already?

In bash2, how do I find the name of a script being sourced? has some related information, but no answer.  The lack of BASH_SOURCE in Bash 2.02 makes this a much more difficult problem than it is with later versions of Bash.

Maybe this is just a semantic nit, but a script cannot know which directory "it resides in" because files do not exist in directories.  If you have a file which has a name "foo" in directory /usr/bin and another name "bar" in directory /usr/local/bin, (ie, /usr/bin/foo and /usr/local/bin/bar are both links to the same file), in which directory does the file "reside"?  The question you are asking can only have meaning with respect to the name that was used to source the script.

I'd recommend you do export BASH_SOURCE=source-me/source-me; . $BASH_SOURCE so that your script will run on Solaris 8 and more recent Solaris.

You can set the location when you install the script.
$ pwd
/home/username
$ cat source-me/source-me
IAmHere=/home/username/source-me/source-me
echo "$IAmHere"
$ . source-me/source-me
/home/username/source-me/source-me
$


you could also require the caller to pass the script location as an argument but sanity checking that the value passed is appropriate will be harder
